# Correct misspelled [smart-conract] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

There's a widely used but misspelled tag on the main site: [smart-conract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-conract).

♦ moderators can easily change that by merging the tag into [smart-contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contract); it doesn't matter that that tag does not exist yet. See the bottom paragraph of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/295232).

Comment: Thanks for reporting. @Ismael comment probably should be posted as answer.